Order type of cuts satisfying $\mathsf I\Sigma_n$
When $M$ is a model of Peano arithmetic, a cut of $M$ is an initial segment $I$ of $M$ such that $I$ is closed under successor. There is some work on cuts that satisfy $\mathsf I\Sigma_n$, Peano arithmetic with induction only for $\Sigma_n$ formulae, such as in Paris's paper "A hierarchy of cuts in models of arithmetic".
Where $M$ is a nonstandard model of Peano arithmetic and $n\geq 1$ is a natural number, let $\mathrm{Cut}_{\mathsf I\Sigma_n}(M)$ be the set of cuts of $M$ that satisfy $\mathsf I\Sigma_n$, and $\prec$ be the initial segment relation. Since all cuts of $M$ are initial segments of $M$, we have that $\prec$ is a linear order on $\mathrm{Cut}_{\mathsf I\Sigma_n}(M)$. In order to possibly better understand the structure of models of $\mathsf I\Sigma_n$ that nonstandard models of Peano arithmetic must include, given a natural number $n\geq 1$, what is the minimal (under order-preserving embedding) possible order type of $(\mathrm{Cut}_{\mathsf I\Sigma_n}(M),\prec)$ for a nonstandard model of Peano arithmetic $M$?
Friedman showed in 1973 that every countable nonstandard model of Peano arithmetic is isomorphic to an initial segment of itself, so when $M$ is countable, $\mathrm{Cut}_{\mathsf I\Sigma_n}(M)$ is not well-founded under $\prec$. Some more work which could be helpful for this problem may be in Paris's paper, which appears in Lecture Notes in Mathematics vol. 834, "Model Theory of Algebra and Arithmetic" (1980), however I personally do not understand the results well enough to apply them.
